# I want to know if it's true: $\sin(\pi/2+2k\pi)>\sin(3\pi/2+6k\pi)$

Tags: trigonometry

I want to know if it's true.

$$\sin(\pi/2+2\pi K)>\sin(3(\pi/2+2\pi k))$$

and also

$$\sin(-\pi/2+2\pi K)<\sin(3(-\pi/2+2\pi k))$$
if it's true for all $K$

thanks

Comment: If $k$ is an integer, then $\sin(\pi/2+2k\pi)=\sin(\pi/2)$ and $\sin\bigl(\, 3 (\pi/2+2k\pi \,)\bigr)=\sin(3\pi/2+6k\pi)=\sin(3\pi/2)$.

Comment: so it's true for all integer k? right

Comment: In the expression $ \ 2k \pi \ $ , $ \ k \ $ tells you the number of full circles that are made from the angle that term is added to, since "once around" is $ \ 2 \pi \ $ radians.  (So $ \ 6k \pi \ $ tells you the number of times _three_ complete circles are made.)

Comment: @user2999009, more generally, you can always apply $$\sin C-\sin D$$ http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $k \in N$
$ \sin(\pi/2+2k\pi)=\sin(\pi/2)=1\\\sin(3\pi/2+6\pi k)=\sin(3\pi/2)=-1 \implies 1>-1\\\sin(-\pi/2+2\pi k)=\sin(-\pi/2)=-1\\\sin(-3\pi/2+6\pi k)=\sin(-3\pi/2)=1 \implies -1<1$

You can use the fact that for the proof for the above $\sin(a\pm b)=\sin(a)\cos(b)\pm \sin(b)\cos(a)$